# Run Core 2.0.x on server with 2.1 installed

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a Windows Server 2016 with Core 2.1 installed and one 2.1 application running on it. I tried to setup another application built on Core 2.0.5 on the server but running that gives me the IIS 502.5 Error and looking in the EventViewer show the ErrorCode '0x80004005 : 8000808c

This error seems to be pointing at that the correct version of dotnet Core is not installed. Is the 2.1 version not backwards compatible with 2.0.x and in that case can I install the latest 2.0.x runtime without disturbing the existing 2.1 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run the app without IIS, Kestrel only. In command line browse to app directory and launch it with `dotnet WebApplication1.dll` (change to point to proper dll). There may be missing dependencies and it informs you about them gracefully.

```
F:\WebApplication1>dotnet WebApplication1.dll
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (WebApplication1.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore', version: '2.1.1'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll'
  This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application was published using the following target manifest files:
    aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-linux-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-osx-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-win7-x64.xml;aspnetcore-store-2.0.0-win7-x86.xml
```

You can install as many runtimes or SDKs as you wish, when installing new ones old are kept intact (and the other way around). You can list installed runtimes with command `dotnet --list-runtimes`

```
C:\>dotnet --list-runtimes
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Comment: Thanks! Running the application i Kestrel showed that exact error message and installing the 2.0.8 version of Core solved the issue. Again, thank you!